# iterating though two arrays to output values

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I have two arrays a name array and a values array they are a string and double respectively. I want to be able for a user to type in a textfield and to iterate though the name array until there is a match then output the value that has the same number as the name to be outputted

this is the code i have:

```
    for(var i = 0; i<name.count; i++){
        if name[i] == typeFood{
            yieldOutput == percent[i]

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `find` to locate the location of the value in the `name` array, then use the returned index to look up the percent:

```
if let idx = find(name, typeFood) {
    yieldOutput = percent[idx]
}
```

You can also combine the two actions together with `map` to declare an output variable using `let`:

```
if let foodPercentage = find(name, typeFood).map({ percent[$0] }) {
    // foodPercentage will have a value here
}
else {
    // not-found logic here
}
```

Comment: but when i use that i get this error:   Cannot invoke 'find' with an argument list of type '([String], UITextField!)'

Comment: Ah, that’s because you presumably want to pass `find` the `.text` property of your text field, rather than the text field itself.